# How can we get the transport method in javascript client for signalr core?

Tags: signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

In older versions of signalR, you could do this to get the transport method being used:

```
$.connection.hub.transport.name
```

How is this done for signalR core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the HubConnectionBuilder, you can get the transport like so:

```
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(connectionUrl)
    .build();

this.connection.connection.transport.constructor.name
```

Perhaps not the best solution, but it seems to work well enough. Looks like the returned values could be:

- WebSocketTransport
- LongPollingTransport
- ServerSentEventsTransport